# iPhoto update not available

Tags: photos.app, software-update

iPhoto won't open on my computer, insisting I need to update before using it, but when I click "check for updates" it informs me that there are no updates in the Australian store!!

Very frustrating, I don't use it a lot, but annoying that I can't use it until I update with a non-existent update!

Is there anyway around this? I'm not sure if I can download it from another countries store?

Lou

Comment: Please edit your question and add tags to indicate what version of Mac OS X is on your Mac, (or what version of Windows is on your PC,) and the current installed version of iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Does iPhoto show up under `Purchased` tab of your `Mac App Store`? If yes, you can try deleting the app from **/Applications** and try installing (downloading) it again from `Purchased` tab.

[image]

[image]